# DTO framework for PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, dto

Is there any PHP framework to manage **DTO** (Data Transfer Object) and the **mapping** of DTOs to the Domain Model ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [tutorial explaining the implementation](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php/practical-php-patterns-data) of this paradigm, it may help a little.

Or if you are interested to solve your problem with other paradigms:

Perhaps, if you wish, you can be useful to use the [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=7&catname=Database). Specifically, the MDB2 package (database abstraction layer), which implements the abstraction layer to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me DTO is about transferring data as objects between applications. In PHP this can be done by using any of the available data storage containers, including JSON, DOM(XML) and XML.

Since DTO is a paradigm, I'm not sure what framework to suggest since most of them already work this way (although they don't call it as such).

Comment: The thing is I have a complex model domain with domain logic, and a Service layer. I want my Service layer to return basic objects (no domain logic possible), so I was thinking of DTOs. But I don't want to write them and do the data mapping myself, I am looking for a framework to do that.